# XPath query for change structure of xml document

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathquery

I have **xml** file with data:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pets>
    <Pet>
        <id>9223372016900023061</id>
        <name>fish</name>
        <status>available</status>
    </Pet>
    <Pet>
        <id>9223372016900023062</id>
        <name>Mouse</name>
        <status>available</status>
    </Pet>
    <Pet>
        <id>9223372016900023066</id>
        <name>doggie</name>
        <status>available</status>
    </Pet>
    <Pet>
        <id>9223372016900023068</id>
        <name>Puff</name>
        <status>available</status>
    </Pet>
    <Pet>
        <id>9223372016900023069</id>
        <name>doggie</name>
        <status>available</status>
    </Pet>
    <Pet>
        <id>9223372016900023070</id>
        <name>doggie</name>
        <status>available</status>
    </Pet>
  </pets>
```

And I need to create **xpath query** (in format somthing like this: **/pets/Pet..**) which gives output like this:

#9223372016900023061 - fish

#9223372016900023062 - Mouse

#9223372016900023066 - doggie

#9223372016900023068 - Puff

#9223372016900023069 - doggie

#9223372016900023070 - doggie

Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to loop threw every `Pet` in your code you code use this:

```
concat('#',id,' - ', name)
```